# Using map() to initialize array inline from array of Dictionary (i.e. a JSON array)

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

My class can be initialized from a JSON Dictionary

```
class ChildObject {
    required init?(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]) { //init... }
}
```

And now I was given an array of such Dictionaries:

```
// objectDictionaries = [[String:Any]]
```

Now I want to initialize an array of my class inline using `map`. I'm initializing an array inside another class.

```
 class ParentObject {
      var children: [ChildObject]

      required init?(fromDictionary aDictionary: [String:Any]) {
            guard let childDictionaries = aDictionary["children"] as? [[String:Any]],
               let children = childDictionaries.map { ChildObject(fromDictionary: $0) }
               else { return nil }
            self.children = children
      }

 }
```

But this doesn't compile--- can anyone tell me the correct syntax? I tried `forEach` but that also didn't work.

In a playground I get

- Expected else after guard
- Anonymous closure argument not contained in a
  closure
- Expected Expression
- Braces block of statements in an unused
  closure

Comment: Your syntax is look ok you need to show some more code related to `objectDictionaries`

Comment: try by changing `init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any])` to `init(fromDictionary dictionary: [[String:Any]])` bcz json is array of dict. Now make sure your what your data by printing values in console.

Comment: What error are you getting? Does your init method has this exact signature? Is it possible that you have a failable initializer? (`init?(…)`), if so you may need to use `flatMap`.

Comment: @what is the type of `children` in `ParentObject` class? Also add the compiler error that you are getting

Comment: @Nirav, Thanks for your help. Both your and Marco's answer provided the explanation (the result of map would be an optional), but Marco's answer provided a bit more complete code plus accounted for the case where the result of flatmap could not be nil, which I think stays more true to the situation here (init?). Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` doesn't return an optional, so `let children = childDictionaries.map { ChildObject(fromDictionary: $0) }` can't be inside your guard clause.

On the other hand, `ChildObject(fromDictionary: $0)` does return an optional, something that `map` doesn't support.

You could use `flatMap`, so values that can't be initialized will be ignored:

```
class ParentObject {
    let children: [ChildObject]

    required init?(fromDictionary aDictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let childDictionaries = aDictionary["children"] as? [[String:Any]],
        else { return nil }

        self.children = childDictionaries.flatMap { ChildObject(fromDictionary: $0) }

    }
}
```

You can also return nil if all the children must be properly initialized:

```
    required init?(fromDictionary aDictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let childDictionaries = aDictionary["children"] as? [[String:Any]]
        else { return nil }

        let children = childDictionaries.flatMap { ChildObject(fromDictionary: $0) }

        guard children.count == childDictionaries.count else { return nil }

        self.children = children
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For both class you are having `init?` it means it will return nil to so when you map the array of dictionary it will give you result `[ParentObject?]` and `[ParentObject?]` it means array object are optional and you are trying to stored result in array of `non-optional`, To solved the problem simply use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689788-flatmap) because it will `ignored/reduce` the `nil` and give you array of `non-optional` objects.

```
class ParentObject {
    var children: [ChildObject]

    required init?(fromDictionary aDictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let childDictionaries = aDictionary["children"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
            return nil 
        }
        self.children = childDictionaries.flatMap { ChildObject.init }
    }

}
```

Same goes for array of `ParentObject`

```
self.parents = objectDictionaries.flatMap { ParentObject.init }
```

**Note:** Return type of `map` is not the `optional` so remove it from the `guard let` like I have done.